# Background image with gradient color not working in chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the webkit gradient tag with image for Chrome, the gradient color working but image doesn't show in chrome. I've tried it in Firefox and the image and gradient color working fine.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(74,40,73,.8), 
rgb(147,98,143,.8)), url(./images/covers/1.jpg) no-repeat;
```

```css
.profile-card {

 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(74,40,73,.8), rgb(147,98,143,.8)), url(./images/covers/1.jpg) no-repeat;
  
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #4A2849, #93628F), url(./images/covers/1.jpg) no-repeat;  /* image not working in chrome */
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 90px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: #fff;

  }
```

```html
<div class="profile-card">
          <img src="images/users/user-1.jpg" alt="user" class="profile-photo">
          <h5><a href="#" class="text-white">abc 
        </div><!--profile ends-->
```

but in chrome i have tried with this code

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #4A2849, #93628F), 
url(./images/covers/1.jpg) no-repeat;
```

but the image does not show in chrome.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and add a snippet with a lorempixel picture

Comment: `-webkit-` is used for IE and Edge, not Chrome. Chrome uses the standard.

Comment: @EGxo in my Chrome OSX, I only see colour in B in the snippet I made

Answer (score 0):

Use **rgba** instead of **rgb**, like:

```css
.a { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(74,40,73,.8), 
rgba(147,98,143,.8)), url(./images/covers/1.jpg) no-repeat;  
}

.b {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #4A2849, #93628F), 
url(./images/covers/1.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
```